# Retrieving an particular element from JSONArray

Tags: java, arraylist, arrays

How can I retrieve "B2" from the following? JSONArray?

```
        JSONArray o = new JSONArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
        list.add("B" + i);
        list.add(100+i);
        o.put(list);
    }
```

I'm thinking it's something like the following, although this isn't at all correct.

```
o.get(2)[0]
```

Comment: No, it would be `o.getInt(2)`. See http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html#getInt%28int%29

Comment: the second entry isn't an integer? it was a list of size 2.

Comment: `o.getJSONArray(2).getString(0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using [`put()`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html#put%28java.util.Collection%29), which:

> Put a value in the JSONArray, where **the value will be a JSONArray** which is produced from a Collection.

So, this will add an array into your array. Something like this:

```
[
  [
    "B1", "B2"
  ]
]
```

If this was intended, then you'll first need to get the inner array and then it's second entry:

```
o.getJSONArray(0).getInt(1);
```

Otherwise, if you want to *fill* your existing `JSONArray o` with the entries from the `List`, you'll want to use the [`JSONArray(Collection)`-constructor](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html#JSONArray%28java.util.Collection%29).

Answer (score 0):

You've created an array of bidimensional arrays.
The following code snippet should work:

```
o.getJSONArray(2).getString(0);
```